# highcharts rangeSelectorZoom label

Tags: highcharts

I want to change the highcharts rangeSelectorZoom into another text. I've tried 2 ways but I haven't got a result!

1.

```
    Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang: {
        rangeSelectorZoom: 'myzoom'
    }
});
```

2.

```
            lang:{
        rangeSelectorZoom: 'myzoom'
        },
```

Please help me...

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use first option and as I see it works properly:

```
 Highcharts.setOptions({
            lang:{
                rangeSelectorZoom:'myownzoom'
            }
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rqs2M/

Comment: Yes, this is the first method I've used and is true.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what rangeSelectorZoom is, but I can only find two optons in the highcharts API: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#lang.resetZoom

```
lang:{
    resetZoom:"reset zoom",
    resetZoomTitle:"Reset zoom level 1:1"
}
```

Do either of those do what you want ? If not, give us some more details of what you're trying to change.

Comment: Yes, this is what the API has, but I tried it before and I couldn't get answer. This may is a bug. The first method I've used is correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    lang:{
        resetZoom:'ResetZoom!'
    }
});
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This code works for me. But "resetZoomTitle", "rangeSelectorZoom" - does not.